# method parameter, instance variable

Tags: java, variables, methods, instance

In the following code I have `this.name= name`, when I print out I get a name of the student.
However when I change my code for `name= this.name`, I receive null in the print out, why is that?
Or when I further change `name = name`.

```
public Student(String name, String groupName, int javaProf, String cprNumber, Gender gender) {
        this.name=name; 

        //"name" refers to method parameter and "this.name" refers to the instance variable. Instance field
        //takes precedence over method parameter and avoids name clash

        this.groupName = groupName;
        this.javaProf = javaProf;
        this.cprNumber = cprNumber;
        this.gender = gender;
        this.courses = new HashMap<>();
    }
}
```

Comment: The answer to your question is hidden in the comment in the code snippet. :)

Comment: Because `this` refers to your instance variables.

Comment: If you change the code to `name = this.name`, that's setting the parameter value to the field value, which will be null by default. Why would you do that?

Comment: Read [The Java Tutorials: Using the this Keyword](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html)

Comment: @ Jon Skeet it was a question in one of the exercises to understand the concept of parameter and instance variable better, thank you for all the replies.

Answer (score 2):

The comment says it all: `name` refers to the method parameter, while `this.name` refers to the instance variable.

If you write

```
name = this.name;
```

you assign the value of the instance variable (which is initially `null`) to the value of the method parameter). Thus, the instance variable stays `null`.

If you write

```
name = name;
```

you assign the value of the method parameter to the value of the method parameter. This is basically a no-op. So also, the value of the instance variable stays `null`.

Comment: Thank you so much for the clear explanation, Im beginner in Java, therefore a bit hard to grasp the concept

Answer (score 1):

Well, that's simple to understand, your method takes "name" as an argument and your class has a variable with exactly the same name "name", in java we use the reserved word "this" to reference the variable in a class. In this case this.name references the variable "name" in the Student class while "name" references the argument of the constructor method.

Then name = this.name returns null value simply because this.name has not yet been initialized

Answer (score 0):

this.name=name --> Global Variable (probably empty) = method variable (probably data).

name (it has the data)=this.name (what probably is null), make both variables be null.

Comment: Thank you, i've benefited from all the explanations!